# TypeError is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

Попалось мне сие чудо в руки. http://jsfiddle.net/82zah5pd/
Раньше все это работало. Потом перестало(видимо что-то было исправлено).

Суть кода в следующем.При нажатии на кнопку-открывается svg окно
Но оно открывается только если на странице 1 кнопка открывающая это окно и собственно само окно.

Если кнопки две и окна тоже 2 - ничего не работает.
Вот читаемый вид там где 1 кнопка - http://rghost.ru/8pDtBbknj
А вот где уже 2 кнопки - http://rghost.ru/7ksCcGDNs
Отличия там вот в чем:
Создали копию файла dialogFx.js(dialoggFx.js). В нем поменяли

```
this.ctrlClose = this.el.querySelector( '[data-dialog-close]' );
```

На

```
this.ctrlClose = this.el.querySelector( '[dato-dialog-close]' );
```

В самом html файле изменения видны(просто все копировали и поменяли data на doto, somedialog на homedialog)
Вообщем тихий ужас который еще и не работает.
Соответственно вопрос: Как заставить этот код работать(желательно конечно не использовать вариант *овнокода как в примере), но главное что бы работало

Comment: Совет на будущее: используйте системы контроля версий (git, bzr)

Comment: `dato-dialog-close` - это аттрибут в хтмл - проверь есть он или он там `doto-dialog-close` - в любом случае лучше вернуть `data` - как стандартный префикс для пользовательских атрибутов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся проблема заключается в конструкторе

```
function DialogFx( el, options ) {
```

конкретно в строчке

```
this.ctrlClose = this.el.querySelector( '[dato-dialog-close]' );
```

здесь жестко указано, что ищем элемент с атрибутом `dato-dialog-close`, но в разметке - из двух диалогов такой атрибут есть только в одном.

поэтому для другого диалога - это селектор возвращал `null` и соответственно падал когда пытался навесить ему обработчик для *click*.

В качестве решения нужно привести к однообразному виду все: например оставить в js `'[dato-dialog-close]'` и в html поменять все `-dialog-close` на `dato-dialog-close`.

Comment: Смотрите,что получается.В html мы один раз подключаем dialogFx.js.В котором атрибут data.В html две кнопки у одной атрибут data, у другой dato.Два дива с разными id(somedialog, homedialog).Не смотря на то,что у кнопок открывающих эти окна разные атрибуты-у закрывающих кнопок-одинаковые-data.И в самом скрипте внизу страницы все разное.data к somedialog, dato к homedialog.Почему везде все разное.Кроме кнопок закрытия-там только data.Ума не приложу как это работает.

Comment: @HoPkInS, я не понял что вы хотели сказать :-) ответ помог или нет? или не пробовали?

Comment: Ответ помог.Я просто не пойму почему работает в том случае.

Comment: @HoPkInS, а я уже запутался :-) суть в том, что при создании передавали ссылки на конкретные элементы `somedialog = document.getElementById( dlgtrigger.getAttribute( 'data-dialog' ) ),
     dlg = new DialogFx( somedialog );` и `homedialog = document.getElementById( dlgtrigger.getAttribute( 'dato-dialog' ) ),
     dlg = new DialogFx( homedialog );` поэтому у нас все элементы есть, но кнопку закрытия мы определяем уже в конструкторе, а не передаем снаружи, поэтому падал когда не находил ее

Comment: Я мыслил в эту сторону,но.Почему тогда когда мы подключаем два одинаковых js файла.В котором как раз указываем data в одном и dato в другом...и в самом html тоже две разные кнопки закрытия....то ничего не работает.При такой конструкции-работает все,но по 1 элементу.1 блок,1 кнопка и т.д.и не важно.dato везде или data.Но стоит подключить два js.C разными атрибутами-все падает.

Comment: потому что в яваскрипте нет перегрузок - если подключил два файла с одинаковыми функциями в итоге будет выполнятся так которая подключена последней

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32110/discussion-between-grundy-and-hopkins).